# Assigning full file path to an array in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, find, grep

I would like to know how I can assign values to an array in bash like I try here:

```
declare -a array
find */*file.txt > array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what you want, you need to change this:

```
declare -a array
find */*file.txt > array
```

to this:

```
array=(*/*file.txt)
```

(which will set `array` to an array containing the names of all files matching `*/*file.txt`).